# MS EXCEL and a CUSTOM WEBSITE

Tags: java, excel, vba, web, publish

Community,

Could someone help me understand the basics of creating a website which calls MS Excel for data/calculations?

I have created a fairly robust Excel workbook which does thousands of calculations with the use of VBA macros. The ultimate goal is to be able to create a simple website for which users can visit to get results.

------ UPDATE -------

As I've learned, it is not possible to create a website which uses MS Excel as its calculations engine. Instead, one would need to build a stand-alone application which doesn't require MS Office. Basically, I have spent about 80 hours porting over a 300 hour Excel project onto a .NET desktop application. It was the best option for me. I researched & tried Java, C++, PHP, and other languages before I finally settled on .NET.

The toughest part is just figuring out how to store/retrieve/update the data necessary for your project. From there, transferring from VBA to .NET is fairly simple. The next steps for me will be to make a Web Application (with the use of Visual Studio 2012) that mirrors my desktop application. And finally, I'll just build the website. Once I'm done I will give an update for anyone out there who has built an Excel project which they'd like to take to the web.

Thanks - to all who've given advice.

Comment: In my opinion, your application would be better served by writing code that performs the same calculations that the spreadsheet does.  Excel doesn't work well this way.

Comment: All of the calculations are done in VBA. The only things on the spreadsheet are a dozen-or-so lookup tables. The spreadsheet essentially just provides the structure & familiarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **website**: not really. You need msoffice to run the sheet, so unless you manually execute the sheet previously so that the data is available for read (not execute) you can't do it with ms excel. You can do it with a programming language, depending on what you need and what you are familiar with you have many options VB(script) should be the simplest and PHP the most powerful of the most known. After just learn about the math specific issues and functions!
2. **server**: sure you can use that laptop, but it not only stores but also processes the page requests. Remember it should be set up properly with web serving software. Connecting by cable would be safe but the question is how reliable do you want it to be? A home connection and weak server might not be so reliable but it works fine for testing and small scenarios otherwise it's simpler to just hire a hosting solution. May cost from 15$ to 60$ for a basic site depending on what you need.

P.S.: there is an easy to use server software called xampp that runs smoothly on windows. It supports many languages and databases.

**A1.** Yes, a scripting language it's much slower and overall less capable, it depends on what you want to achieve if VB is enough.

**A2.** It is most powerful when it comes to calculations because it runs on the server and is versatile. for data storage i recommend databases but that can be complicated for you.

**A3.** No, you can't abandon HTML it is essential to web pages like a core structure.

**new A1.** Java is also powerful and more portable than php but with more issues since it runs client side. Jsp runs server side and is like php. Potatoes potAtoes. Start by choosing a language maybe but remember scripting languages are usually client side which means it depends on the users pc and the code is available to them.

**new A2.** Maybe not the best choice, but workable.

**new A3.** Excel speed is closer to php/server side languages i would recommend php for many reasons. Secure fast precise (no rounding) powerful many math functions might also have a few financial, not sure.

**new A4.** Yes, PHP and HTML work fine together but remember one runs on the server and HTML on the client.

**new A5.** Many on the web, also "php for dummies" as a book is a starting point.

**new A6.** You got me there, I'm not familiar with R.

Comment: DJ; thanks for the help. I'm disappointed about Excel being obsolete for feeding a website. Well, I think I'm going to lean towards VB scripts; because it would play a bigger role in my career (I am not a programmer/developer).

Comment: You should edit your question instead of commenting, this is not a forum. Java is also powerful and more portable than php but with more issues since it runs client side. Jsp runs server side and is like php. Potatoes potAtoes. Start by choosing a language maybe but remember scripting languages are usually client side which means it depends on the users pc and the code is available to them.

Comment: You can thank me with upvoting... :) i will transfer all my answers on these comments to my original anwser 2+o asap

Comment: You should also move your first 3 questions on these comments or at least include then in your main question for reference.

Comment: DJ, I've gone through an introductory guide to PHP; and I'm really skeptical about its use. Mainly speaking, I strongly dislike how it builds 3D arrays. They are not standard. Instead, I'd have to build an array within an array within an array. Which is something I'd like to stay away from like the plague.

Comment: ►Can PHP really be used to build its very own application? The tutorial I used had the PHP code embedded entirely within the HTML source code. I don't want my code available to the public. Plus, it is very elaborate; and it would take up hundreds of pages. Can PHP do its duty outside of HTML? Can it build a program on its own?

Comment: I don't follow your array issue, what is standard? About php coding you're getting out wrong. Although you write both php and html on the same document the php part is processed on the server and only the html is sent to the client! Try a php hello world first!